# how to reset all invalid fields of a mongoid document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a [mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html) document (in a rails app) that has failed validation. I want to reset all of the invalid fields. Currently I am doing this:

```
@product.errors.each do |e,m|
  method_name = "reset_#{e}!"
  @product.send(method_name)
end
```

This is ok, but is there not a better (more concise) way to do this? I've read the [dirty tracking documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dirty) and googled, but I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean with 'more concise' but you don't need use "send"

```
@product.errors.errors.each do |f|
  @product[f] = c.changes[f.to_s].first
end
```